# How does the application know the controller class when i do an ActionLink? ASP mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When i do `@Html.ActionLink("About us", "About", "Home")`, how does the application know that the controller file is in `Controllers\HomeController.cs`? I see controller folders separated such as *'Views\Home', 'Views\Booking'* etc. However, how does it know to look for `Controllers\HomeController.cs` when the controller name specified was `Home`? My code is perfectly working due to visual studio's generated files. However, i would like to know what is the theory behind it. Please explain, thank you.

Here is my route config,

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

here is my HomeController,

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {            
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't. It'll just generate the link `/Home/About`, not caring whether a controller for that route exists, and if so, what file it comes from. It does take configured routes in account.

Comment: @CodeCaster i see, my `/home/About` is About.cshtml, does this mean that it loads About.cshtml first? And for some reason, the About.cshtml gives off the controller file name? I have updated the route config inside the question. Please give you expert advice. Thanks!

Comment: the connection is between the route and the controller, the view doesn't come into play, it is determined by the controller. In your /home/About-case, the controller is determined by the "home"-Part of your route. MVC has some fixed rules that for instance turn a route with controller "Home" into a route that uses a class HomeController (if that exists). You can see in your default route, that the first part of the URL makes up the controller name, the second part the action name, the last part is the parameter used when calling the action.

Comment: https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing might be helpful.

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek Yes sir i understand you. However, could you please further explain on the part where you said, "MVC has some fixed rules that for instance turn a route with controller "Home" into a route that uses a class HomeController (if that exists).". Yes, HomeController exists. Can you please guide me to the part (or perhaps file/code?) where the rules set such that when "Home" is specified it routes to HomeController.cs? I hope you understand! Thank you!

Comment: @user859385 you'd have to dig into the MVC sources. Afaik there is no fixed "Home" = "HomeController"-mapping. It is a "<something>" = "<Something>Controller"-mapping. Most likely in the standard MVC routing classes. If you add another controller and e.g. name it "HappyController" with an Action "Laugh", you can access it with the URL /Happy/Laugh. The framework adds the "Controller" part to the class name on its own.

Comment: Yes. Now i understand. So its actually not very complicated. Great! Thats cleared up! @user2326106 helped me with his answer too! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, it's all .net mvc doing this. So when you feed it that ActionLink, it knows that "Home" is the Controller which houses a function named About.

When it's time to invoke the function to render something; the DefaultControllerFactory .net mvc uses will be start enough to figure out that the given controller is missing the word "Controller", so it will append it prior to invocation.

There's a really nice guide I've used in the past about how to override  the DefaultControllerFactory:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/599189/DefaultControllerFactory-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Which might give you a better sense of what's going on under the hood :)

Comment: Thank you! Your answer and @Dirk Trilsbeek comments helped me out! Great link to know whats under the hood (: